# Split javascript code into multiple files but keep relying on lexical scoping

Tags: javascript

How can I split my javascript code into multiple files but keep relying on lexical scoping to share variables between parts of my codebase ?

If my code is short, I write things like this, where `cmpnt` accesses the `emit` function through its parent scope. I like this approach, `cmpnt` is defined inline in its parent because this is where it needs to stay ;

```js
function ui() {

  function emit(name) {
    console.debug(name)
  }

  function cmpnt(name) {
    emit(name, ' says hello !')
  }

  cmpnt('first compoenent')
  cmpnt('second component')
}

ui()
```

But when the `cmpnt` code gets longer, I split my code into mulitple files and I end up writing code like this, where I use a module to make a closure with the `emit` function :

```js
// component.js file
function cmpntFactory(emit) {
  return function component(name) {
    emit(name, ' says hello !')
  }
}

// ui.js file
function ui() {

  function emit(name) {
    console.debug(name)
  }
  var cmpnt = cmpntFactory(emit)
  cmpnt('first compoenent')
  cmpnt('second component')
}

ui()
```

I'm not ok with that : I split my code into multiple files only because it's easier to read in my text editor, but not because I was looking for modularity (in this special case, I know modularity is good). A closure will be created in any browser accessing my website, only because I prefer dealing with small files, and that's something I don't really like.

Is there any way to avoid this ? The only way I can think of is using a build system that would allow me to include raw content from one file into another. Does that kind of system exist ? Or am I missing something, and there's an easier way to do that ?

Comment: You mention "without adding any level of abstraction" yet have a "compile time". Why not use one of the existing module systems out there?

Comment: i recently discovered a really powerful system for injecting little files into bigger ones, even in the middle of ES6 template strings and <template> tags, where client-side JS can easily reach it. It's called PHP, and it's got lots of options for code bundling. ex: `return \`<?php include '_item_editor.html'; ?>\`;`

Comment: Are placing the js files in the correct order?

Comment: As I understand it, all the JavaScript files get concatenated anyway. You might just need to include the script tags in the correct order in your HTML.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer It's part of an experiment where I try to stick to a "minimalist" approach and avoid any unnecessary abstraction : accessing the parent scope is enough, and if I'm sure there's no penalty performance with the module pattern approaches, I don't want to create a closure in any browser accessing my website only because it's easier for me to deal with small files in my text editor. The kind of macro system I mentionned will maybe add some complexity, but no abstraction.

Comment: @Will Only the global scope will be shared by multiple files, not the local scope of the ui function in my example.

Comment: @jkdev Only the global scope will be shared by multiple files, not the local scope of the ui function in my example.

Comment: @dandavis Hmm, ok, but not really what I was expecting...